# Save recorded file as mp4 audio

Tags: ios4

> **How can we save the recorded file as mp4 audio format in objective
>   c .**
>   Can I have to change in the record settings to save as mp4 file.I
>   have coded record settings as follow.Would u please help me to
>   customize record settings for saving recorded audio file as mp4
>   format.

```
recordSettings= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 32000], AVSampleRateKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                       nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(NSURL *) tempFileURL
{

    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mp4"];
    NSLog(@"Saved %@",outputPath);
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:NULL];
    }
    [outputPath release];
    return [outputURL autorelease];
}
```